# GraphDB's Visual Graph does not show any visible connections

Tags: graphdb

Here's what I have (using a Mac):

- An ontology was created in Protege (v5), incorporating some classes
  from established ontologies.
- All classes were given the same Base URI.
- HermiT, FacT++, Pellet, and Ontop plugin reasoners were used to test the ontology in Protege, and no errors or messages were returned.
- Protege's Ontop plugin (v1.8) was used to map the classes to
  postgres RDBS column headers (table_column) and exported the R2RML
  mapping file.
- The Ontop CLI was used to materialize triples through a
  jdbc postgres connection the ontology in `turtle` format, according to
  the R2RML `.ttl mappings` file.

Here's where my interactions with GraphDB (v8.2) start:

- The GraphDB repository was created with an OWL2-RL profile with the 'read only' unchecked.
- All ontology and materialized data triples were uploaded to GraphDB through `graphdb-import` folder in `turtle` format. All options checked on upload, and the same Base URI was provided.
- The Class Hierarchy diagram suggests that the imported triples are properly structured.
- The Class Relationship circular network graph shows reasonable
  relationships between the largest 10 classes.
- The Domain-Range graph shows a number of in-going and out-going connections to nodes/individuals with predicates.
- SPARQL queries appear to return expected values.

Here's my problem:  When I enter the Visual Graph, I don't see anything. When I search and select a value that should have nodes, all I see is the single node with a message "This node has no visible connections."

What does this mean and where can I start troubleshooting?  Or is the Visual Graph buggy?

Comment: Please post your ontology and materialized data triples.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45102058/7879193) (scroll down to the "UPDATE" section).

Comment: I reached out to GraphDB and I'm currently troubleshooting.  Apparently this Visual Graph feature filters out all rdf and owl classes to represent just part of the graph.  In my situation, I used object properties in creating subclasses ('a class' and ('an objectProperty' some 'xsd:string')), and this doesn't explicitly create Domain-Range relationships with objectProperties. So I had no explicit relations, which could account for the behavior I was seeing.